# How to pass data from current page to another page?

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I created a simple shopping cart in my PHP File, I'm using session for this, I am able to display the orders click and displayed in the cart.ph perfectly. Now I added a quantity text field for each items ordered by the customer in my cart page. now I want Summary page with product name and quantity inputted by the customers in his/her but apparently I can only get one product in cart with correct quantity and the rest is default to 1 here is my code

Here is my cart.ph

```
<?php
session_start();
$status="";
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=="remove"){
if(!empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {
    foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $key => $value) {
        if($_POST["code"] == $key){
        unset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$key]);
        $status = "<div class='box' style='color:red;'>
        Product is removed from your cart!</div>";
        }
        if(empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))
        unset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
            }       
        }
}

if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=="change"){
  foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as &$value){
    if($value['code'] === $_POST["code"]){
        $value['quantity'] = $_POST["quantity"];
        break; // Stop the loop after we've found the product
    }
}
    
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>SKIP-CART</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:700px; margin:50 auto;">

<h2>Shopping Cart</h2>   

<?php
if(!empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {
$cart_count = count(array_keys($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]));
?>
<div class="cart_div">
<a href="cart.php">
<img src="cart-icon.png" /> Cart
<span><?php echo $cart_count; ?></span></a>
</div>
<?php
}
?>

<div class="cart">
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])){
    $total_price = 0;
?>  
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>ITEM NAME</td>
<td>QUANTITY</td>
</tr>   
<?php       
foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $product){
?>
<tr>
<td><img src='<?php echo $product["image"]; ?>' width="50" height="40" /></td>
<td><?php echo $product["name"]; ?><br />
<form method='post' action=''>
<input type='hidden' name='code' value="<?php echo $product["code"]; ?>" />
<input type='hidden' name='action' value="remove" />

<button type='submit' class='remove'>Remove Item</button>
</form>
</td>
<td>
<form method='post' action='display.php' id='orderform'>
<input type='hidden' name='code' value="<?php echo $product["code"]; ?>" />
<input type='hidden' name='action' value="change" /> 
<input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity">                                                                                                                                                                                                 
</select>
</form>
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<?php

}
?>
<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="right">

<strong><button type="submit" form="orderform" value="submit">Proceed Order</button></strong>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>        
  <?php
}else{
    echo "<h3>Your cart is empty!</h3>";
    }
?>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<div class="message_box" style="margin:10px 0px;">
<?php echo $status; ?>
</div>



<br/><br />

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my display.php this file will get all the products from cart and quantity edited by the customer/user but apparently i can only display 1 correct quantity record base on cart.php

```
<?php

session_start();
$status="";
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=="remove"){
if(!empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {
    foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $key => $value) {
        if($_POST["code"] == $key){
        unset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$key]);
        $status = "<div class='box' style='color:red;'>
        Product is removed from your cart!</div>";
        }
        if(empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))
        unset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
            }       
        }
}

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>SKIP-CART</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:700px; margin:50 auto;">

<h2>Shopping Cart</h2>   

<?php
if(!empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {
$cart_count = count(array_keys($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]));
?>
<div class="cart_div">
<a href="cart.php">
<img src="cart-icon.png" /> Cart
<span><?php echo $cart_count; ?></span></a>
</div>
<?php
}
?>

<div class="cart">
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])){
    $total_price = 0;
?>  
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>

</tr>   
<?php       
foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $product){
?>
<tr>
<td><img src='<?php echo $product["image"]; ?>' width="50" height="40" /></td>
<td><?php echo $product["name"]; ?><br />
</td>
<td><?php echo $product["quantity"]; ?><br />
</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<?php

}
?>
<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="right">

<strong><button type="submit" form="orderform" value="submit">Proceed Order</button></strong>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>        
  <?php
}else{
    echo "<h3>Your cart is empty!</h3>";
    }
?>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<div class="message_box" style="margin:10px 0px;">
<?php echo $status; ?>
</div>



<br/><br />

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the sample image for Cart:

[image: Cart.php]

when I click proceed order this is my display.php

[image: display.php]

Comment: Your “Proceed Order” submit button does not appear to be part of any of those forms to begin with, so I don’t see how you would get data for even _one_ product submitted with this …?

Comment: i get the data from the session i created which is shopping_cart so i can display data from the session i created but i cant display the quantity in the summary page base from the cart.php i can only display 1 correct quantity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to keep all this in the database.

Create the `carts` table and add all the fields you need there, and in the beginning after id make string `uuid`.

For each client who visits your site, create a `uuid` and put it in cookies, and when adding users to the basket, create an entry in the database with this `uuid`. `uuid` will be the user id. If you have a login, then use `user_id`. and then output from the database by `uuid` or by `user_id` if there is a user login.

It will be convenient for you to display a record from the database than to fill out a server session

Comment: creating cart in database? a really bad idea! that can kill the database, as the data file will grow bigger and bigger and at the end you will run out of space, removing those records won't fix the problem; there are sessions for that, database should never be used as a temporary storage

Comment: The basket should always be stored in a database with order status. In the future, there will be online payments, order statistics and other data that will be attached to the order table using cart_id. Of course you decide. But the database is the best option.

Comment: but not before it's made, between ordering screens

Comment: @FlashThunder thats correct, so i use session for this one. apparently i cant get the correct data from the cart.php which is the quantity inputted by the user